# How to retrieve only the comment on a Snowflake View or Table

Tags: snowflake-schema

I've created a Snowflake Table and View and added comments to both. Is there a query in Snowflake that I can use to **SELECT** only the comment on a Table or View?

```
CREATE SCHEMA dbo

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dbo.dummytable (price number) COMMENT = 'Table Comment'
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'dummytable'

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dbo.dummyView COMMENT = 'View Comment'
    AS SELECT dbo.dummytable.price as price FROM dbo.dummytable
SHOW VIEWS LIKE 'dummyView'

// Something like
SELECT COMMENT FROM dummyView
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the information schema.  Each database has its own schema named INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  You can query it like:

```
select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, table_type, comment
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'DBO'
and table_name in ('DUMMYTABLE', 'DUMMYVIEW')
;
```

This assumes your default database is currently the same as where schema DBO resides.  If not, you will need to fully qualify the metadata table, e.g.

```
from some_db_name.information_schema.tables
```

There is a similar view information_schema.columns which can give you the column-level comments.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (there are probably others) is:

```
show tables;
select “comment” from
table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

You can obviously add a WHERE clause to the 2nd statement to select a specific table.